How to derive this Lie group multiplication formula?
I am trying to understand how to derive the following formula: Let $G$ be a Lie group and $e$ its identity. Let $g=T_eG$ be the Lie algebra of $G$ and let $\exp^{\cdot}: \mathfrak{g}\longrightarrow G$ be the exponential map.
Then the relation between the Lie bracket [·,·]$_{\mathrm{g}}$ and the Lie group multiplication is given by the following important formula:
$[u,v]_{\mathfrak{g}}=\frac{d^2}{dtds}_{t,s=0}\exp^{tu}\exp^{s\nu}\exp^{-tu}\forall u\nu\in\mathfrak{g}.$
Could someone please explain the steps involved or provide a reference that clearly explains how this formula is derived?

First note that
$$\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}\exp^{tu} = u$$
by definition. Now note that $\exp^{tu}\exp^{s\nu}\exp^{-tu}$ is a product of three elements of the $G$, and we can't assume this product commutes. But we can compute the two derivates by using the product rule for $t$-derivative. We have
$$\frac{d}{dt}\exp^{tu}\exp^{s\nu}\exp^{-tu} = u\exp^{tu}\exp^{s\nu}\exp^{-tu}  +\exp^{tu}\exp^{s\nu}(-u)\exp^{-tu}$$
Now plug in $t=0$ and the derivative with respect to $s$ and you get
$$\frac{d^2}{dtds}\Big|_{t,s=0}\exp^{tu}\exp^{s\nu}\exp^{-tu} = uv - vu = [u,v] $$

Thank you very much!   : )
